# How to create a domain transient property for based on a child collection's property on Grails?

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class

I have the following domain classes:

```
class ParentClass {
    String myProperty
    static hasMany = [ childClasses : ChildClass]
}

class ChildClass {
    Date birthday
    static belongsTo = [ parentClass : ParentClass]
}
```

I need to be able to list ParentClasses ordered by the birthdate of their most recent child. It would be best if I were able to use the `params` used in the regular CRUD list pages.

I know I could write a specific rule in the controller for this specific ordering, but I feel like it is not the best solution and that I should use something along the lines of a derived property or a transient property based on a criteria, but couldn't find a way to do it (I'm kind of new to Grails and Hibernate).

Any pointers would be appreciated.

**Edit**: I managed to do this:

```
static mapping = {
    mostRecentBirthday formula: '(
        SELECT c.data
        FROM ChildClass c
        WHERE c.parent_class_id=id
        ORDER BY c.birthday DESC LIMIT 1
    )'
}
```

The only problem I have with this solution is that `parent_class_id` is hard coded in there. Is there a more correct way to write this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, then you can do it like this:

```
def parentClass = new ParentClass(params.id);
// let this be your parentclass 
// you want to have the childs from ordered by birthday

def childListOrderedByBirthday = ChildClass.withCriteria {
    parentClass {
        eq("id", parentClass.id);
    }
    order("birthday", "desc")
}.list()
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate to crudolf's approach is to use a [dynamic finder](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20%28GORM%29.html#5.4.1%20Dynamic%20Finders).  It would look like this:

```
def parentClass = new ParentClass(params.id);

def childListOrderedByBirthday =
        ChildClass.findAllByParentClass(parentClass,
                [sort: "birthday", order: "desc"]);
```

This may be cleaner to read.

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not fully understand your suggestion. With my current solution I can use a <g:sortableColumn> for mostRecentBirthday on my view. How can I do the same with your solution? I'd like to use it as it is more clean.

Comment: I don't think using a dynamic finder will prevent you from using the sortableColumn.  Your original question is actually a little confusing.